# Getting an No data received error when using a large array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using a regular loop but when I put in a large data in the loop it doesn't work, is their any way I can do to put large data in an array?

```
$arr = array('Joe', 'Jack');
$arr2 = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    $arr2[] = $val;
}
print_r($arr2);
```

So when the `$arr` is too large i'm getting a no data received error in the browser,

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look at more lightweight [SplFixedArray](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php). It uses a regular contiguous memory block to store the data, as opposed to the traditional hash structure.

The second way is to play with **memory_limit** parameter, but it is not good idea

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

The third way is to spit your array in chunks

Comment: This is a totally new thing for me, have to look in it deeper, thanks anyways for your help.

Answer (score 0):

-If you're using GET, change it to POST when handling large data.

-Change form type to enctype="multipart/form-data"

-Change `post_max_size` in php.ini

-If still doesn't work, use `ini_set("memory_limit","-1")`